# How to strip type from Javascript FileReader base64 string?

Tags: javascript, base64, strip

I've got the following code in my Javascript:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function () {
    alert(reader.result);
};
```

This shows me the following data:

```
 data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAAAAABX3VL4AAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3gYSDCUgSze0AAAAAA5JREFUCNdjrGJgYmAAAAJ0AH4SDHVIAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

The thing is that I only want the part after the comma. I tried getting it from `reader.result.value`, `reader.result.valueOf()` and some other combinations, but can't find the correct one to JUST get the base64 string starting from after the comma. So a second idea is to simply strip off the comma and all that is before that, but I'm kind of unsure how to do that.

Would anybody have any idea how to get this done? All tips are welcome!

Comment: `var base64result = reader.result.split(',')[1];` or `var base64result = reader.result.substr(reader.result.indexOf(',') + 1);`

Answer (score 208, accepted):

The following functions will achieve your desired result:

```
var base64result = reader.result.split(',')[1];
```

This splits the string into an array of strings with the first item (index 0) containing `data:image/png;base64` and the second item (index 1) containing the base64 encoded data.

Another solution is to find the index of the comma and then simply cut off everything before and including the comma:

```
var base64result = reader.result.substr(reader.result.indexOf(',') + 1);
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uCqC4/).

Comment: Do we know for sure, that a comma will never occur in the base64 string it self? 

If so, very good solutions.

Comment: Yes we know for sure. Base64 encoding uses the characters `[a-z, A-Z, 0-9, +, /]` to encode. `=` is also used for padding. See [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much for your explanation.

Comment: Thanks ! Before reading this answer I used this: `var base64result = reader.result.match(/^data:.+\/(.+);base64,(.*)$/)[2]` which is way, way slower. I guess the complexity of `RegEx` operations are much more comparing to `String.split`

Comment: which one is faster, will split search through the file or quit at the first?

Comment: shouldnt the result to be cast to string before splitting ?  -> const resultString = reader.result as string;  after that we can do the split.

Comment: @Buminda: That depends. `result` is `An appropiate string or ArrayBuffer based on which of the reading methods was used to initiate the read operation.`. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result).

Comment: Isn't there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Running this in jsbench.me tells me that the substring is way way faster than string split. By a factor of 100

Answer (score 27):

```
let reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
 
 reader.onloaded = (e) => {
    let base64String = reader.result.split(',').pop();
 };
```

or

```
let base64String = /,(.+)/.exec(reader.result)[1];
```

Comment: I really like the `.pop()` option vs all other options.

Answer (score 6):

You can try splitting your data using *;base64,*.

```
// In here you are getting the data type. Ex - png, jpg, jpeg, etc. You can use this for any further purposes.
var dataType = reader.result.split(';base64,')[0];

// In here you are getting the base64 string and you can use this for your purpose.
var base64result = reader.result.split(';base64,')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
var base64=reader.result.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
```

Comment: this is only for images

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to replace any kind of data type:

```js
const base64 = reader.result.toString().replace(/^data:(.*,)?/, "");
```