# Base64 to Image File Convertion in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am working on a project where I have to upload an image as form data along with other text fields. I have my file in Base64 string at first, then I convert it into a file before uploading it to the server.

```
const data = await fetch(base64String);
const blob = await data.blob();
const file = await new File([blob], 'avatar', { type: 'image/png' });
```

I logged the `base64String` in the client side before uploading it to the server. Then I upload `file` to the server as a File. Before saving it to MongoDB when I log it as a base64 string again in the server side, I see my string is not the same as before. I feel like while converting the base64 to file in the client side I am doing something wrong. Help me out please.

Comment: I had a similar with PHP. I found out that the base64 string changed during from Front-end to server, because some characters such as spaces or plus were modified

Comment: Check whether this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38658654/how-to-convert-a-base64-string-into-a-file/38659875

Comment: If your intention is to upload as a `File` to the server, where is it that you're un-encoding from base64? It looks like you're passing the still-encoded data to a `Blob`, and then making a file from that. You should unencode using the global `atob()` function, or load the base64 data as a data URI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have figured out my problem. When I take image file input from my computer I get a base64 string like below -

> dataimage/jpegbase64/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAA...

But, when I convert it back into a file it expects a string like below -

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAA....

So, basically, I had to trim the string accordingly to match the expected format and wrote a base64 to file conversion function following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38659875/7018344).
Here is my function to convert a base64 string to an image file

```
export function getFileFromBase64(string64:string, fileName:string) {
  const trimmedString = string64.replace('dataimage/jpegbase64', '');
  const imageContent = atob(trimmedString);
  const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(imageContent.length);
  const view = new Uint8Array(buffer);

  for (let n = 0; n < imageContent.length; n++) {
    view[n] = imageContent.charCodeAt(n);
  }
  const type = 'image/jpeg';
  const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type });
  return new File([blob], fileName, { lastModified: new Date().getTime(), type });
}
```

Comment: This solution did not work in Node 18.18.0 as File is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

`data:image/png;` split function is limited to check with `jpeg` images only, for other cases, it might fail, split can be added based on `base64`, string to trim of first part and get the rest.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Convert Base64 to Javascript File object.

```
const yourBase64 = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAr.....';

const file = new File(
  [Uint8Array.from(btoa(yourBase64), (m) => m.codePointAt(0))],
  'filename.png',
  { type: 'image/png' }
);

console.log(file);
// Output
// File {
//   lastModified: 703536246950,
//   lastModifiedDate: Tue Dec 26 2023 03:30:46...,
//   name: "filename.png",
//   size: 7832,
//   type: "image/png",
//   webkitRelativePath: "",
// }
```